# Azure Media Services encode CCTV media

Tags: azure, encoding, media, codecs

We are building a solution in Azure that will allow users to upload CCTV media content to our site.  This media will then hopefully be encoded by Media Services but I have not found a solid list of codecs that supported by Azure.

Ideally we would like to get these odd formats re-encoded to a more standard format like H264.

Has anyone had to deal with this type of media and making it available?

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-manage-live-encoder-enabled-channels/) may help you figure out input formats.